# After automatic updating Google does not work when no Wifi available

Tags: updates, google, 7.0-nougat, mobile-data

Bought new Huawei P10 LITE two weeks ago with Wifi and LTE. Between then and now  an automatic uodate was loaded (Android or Google ?). Since then Google does not work if no wifi available. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:  Provider forgot to mark "Mobile Internet" when upgrading simple telephone contract to smartphone contract...

Sorry to bother you,                            Bert